# How to create two same name databases in two different MySQL users?

Tags: mysql-5.5

I am using MySQL 5.5 running on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have created two different users as 'root' and 'abc' and I want to create 'Items' database in this both user accounts but I want this two databases separated.

Now my problem is that I have created 'Items' database in root user with 10 tables and when I am trying to create a new user 'abc' then 'Items' database comes automatically in that new user with 10 tables and that is what I don't want to do.

How I can create 2 same name databases in different user accounts with different tables in both DBs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users on MySQL are sharing the same context in terms of databases. So if you are creating a database for one user, it will be also visible to user2.

You could solve this issue by prefixing your tables for each user, e.g. abc_item1 and setting correct privileges via grant for it -- so only one user is allowed to use this table.

Another way would be to just create different databases for each user -- which is I think the MySQL way of doing such things.